# Validating all value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I had a Text box controls for which i used `asp:regularexpressions` to validate the value in `textbox` at the time of data entering but when i click the button it sends the data to database is there any solution to avoid this

Ihe main conduction is not to use javascript 
the code is as follows

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"  ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Id" validationexpression="^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnabc" OnClick="btnabc_click" />
```

Comment: I think the problem in expression. Try the default expression provided in property explorer of regularexpression control.

Comment: no my problem is that i can change regular expression but if even the data entered wrong also the data is submiting to database

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/717731-regular-expression-validator

Comment: Are you using visual studio 2012 and framework 4.5?

Comment: no vs2010 and framework 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data which was verified by regular expression is submited to server because it is asp control which is server control so it was submited

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is invalid.

Use this one instead

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$
```

You can check it using this [Live example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5B0-9a-zA-Z%5D%28%5B-.%5Cw%5D%2a%5B0-9a-zA-Z%5D%29%2a@%28%5B0-9a-zA-Z%5D%5B-%5Cw%5D%2a%5B0-9a-zA-Z%5D%5C.%29%2b%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2,4%7D%29%24&input=passes%3a%0Apascal@nunes.in%0Apascal@nunespascal.com%0A%0Afails%3a%0Atest%0A123%0Ahello@me%0Ahello%2bme.in%0Atest@example.something%0A%0A)

Comment: it was not about the regular expression it is about submiting data to server